# HTML BootStrap Login Form Post Method is Not Working [ No Parameters in The URL ]

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Login Form Code :-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="AcSelector">
                        <img src="skypes.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Bird" hight="180" width="70">
        </div>
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>Login</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row align-items-center remember">
                        <input type="checkbox">Remember Me
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn" input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                    Do not have an account?<a href="#">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the Action Page [ Login.php ] Code is :-

```
<?php
require_once 'Config.php';

$Username = $_GET['Username']; // username variable
$Password = $_GET['Password']; // password variable

$dbCon = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name";

$PDOCon = new PDO($dbCon, $username, $password);

$stmt = $PDOCon->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute([$Username]); 
$rows = $stmt->fetch();
echo 'pass',$rows['password'],'   username ',$rows['username'];

?>
```

the problem is when i use the form the action page is printing **pass username** and no Variables 
its suppose to print the **username** row and the **password** row and **BTW** there is no Parameters when using the form by that i mean the url is **'127.0.0.1/project/Login.php'** not **127.0.0.1/project/Login.php?Username=admin&Password=admin**

Comment: Compare `method="POST"` with `$_GET['Username']`.  Notice anything?  [PHP form handling basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are submitting the form with POST method, the variables will be accessible in the $_POST array.

```
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];
```